# VBA; Fill down last line of an array to match the length of an adjacent column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

So for an early stab at VBA I'm writing a macro:

1. I'm pasting in a set of data that increases in numbers of rows each month; data is well organised with no blank values/columns
2. I have formulae in columns A-L and my data is dropped into columns L-onwards
3. I want to update formulae/columns in A-L to fill down to match the last value in column M

Struggling so if you are able to help with an explanation that would be really appreciated. I know it involved selecting the last row in the A:L - I've got that but I can't work out how to cleanly fill down to match a varying length column M each time.

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'

'
    Range("M1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: Without providing your code, how can we help you?

Comment: cheers @Raystafarian added.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use the top snippet (`lrow`) to get the bottom row, and then just use that in your other methods

```
Sub test()
Dim lrow As Integer
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).row
 Range("A1:A" & lrow).FillDown
 Range("B1:B" & lrow).FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: @UncleBoz if this solves your question, go ahead and click the green checkmark next to the answer to indicate the question has an answer.